# Accompanying person in corporate environment

Tags: word-choice, nouns, business-language

International customers attend the training center of a company for training purposes. Sometimes those customers are accompanied by translators or salespersons. I am looking for a short noun to name those persons in application forms.

Possible candidates:

- escort
- companion
- chaperon or chaperone
- assistant

The customers are not native English speakers. Currently, I refer to them as *accompanying person*.

**Can any of the above words be used in business context?** The word *escort* seems inappropriate (some sort of prostitution service). A *companion* is a friend, maybe a wartime comrade, or a business partner. An *assistant* implies a certain hierarchy between the customer and the person who accompanies him or her. And *chaperone* is a word I've never actually heard. It is probably of French origin and sounds old-fashion, but is probably not suitable here.

Right now, I would either choose *companion* or stick to *accompanying person*.

Comment: For business context, use **associate**.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a business trip to Japan.  Our Japanese partner loaned us one of their employees, who acted as a translator (we were travelling around a lot so needed one) and as a general source of information about how things work over there, where to go for dinner, etc.

He was referred to as our **guide**, but the word **advisor** would also have been appropriate.  I think "guide" fits your situation best.

From https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guide:

```
guide noun [C] (PERSON)
(A2)
a person whose job is showing a place or a particular route to visitors:
```